# Using Wordpress Media Upload on multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, upload, media

Follows the HTML button and text field:

```
<div class="meta-container">
    <div class="label col-2 left">
        <label class="squeeze-label">Imagem Logo:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input class="definir_imagem_url" type="text" size="36" name="super-squeeze-meta[imagemLogo]" value="<?php echo $this->data['imagemLogo']; ?>" />
        <input class="definir_imagem_button button" type="button" value="Definir Imagem" />
        <a id="remover_imagem_logo" class="button remove-bg"><div class="dashicons dashicons-post-trash"></div>Remover Imagem</a>
        <p class="description">Imagem que ficará acima da headline.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="meta-container">
    <div class="label col-2 left">
        <label class="squeeze-label">Imagem Background:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input class="definir_imagem_url" type="text" size="36" name="super-squeeze-meta[imagemBackground]" value="<?php echo $this->data['imagemBackground']; ?>" />
        <input class="definir_imagem_button button" type="button" value="Definir Imagem" />
        <a id="remover_imagem_background" class="button remove-bg"><div class="dashicons dashicons-post-trash"></div>Remover Imagem</a>
        <p class="description">Imagem que ficará no fundo da página. Por padrão será feito upload de uma nova imagem para o Wordpress, caso necessite será possível informar um link externo.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below follows javascript to make button class "definir_imagem_button" open the native wordpress media uploader and insert the selected image URL in their respective text field class "definir_imagem_url":

```
$('.definir_imagem_button').click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var custom_uploader = wp.media({
        title: 'Selecionar Imagem',
        button: {
            text: 'Definir Imagem'
        },
        multiple: false  // Set this to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    })

    .on('select', function() 
    {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('.definir_imagem_url').val(attachment.url);
    })

    .open();

});
```

The problem is that the line `$('.definir_imagem_url').val(attachment.url);` assigns the value for all fields of the class and I need the value to be added only to text field of the respective button that was clicked. What better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your HTML structure will be the same for every button, you can capture which button was clicked and use that to find the nearest `.definir_imagem_url` input.

```
$('.definir_imagem_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btnClicked = $( this );
    var custom_uploader = wp.media({
        title: 'Selecionar Imagem',
        button: {
            text: 'Definir Imagem'
        },
        multiple: false  // Set this to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    })
    .on('select', function() {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $( btnClicked ).parent().children( '.definir_imagem_url' ).val( attachment.url );
    })
    .open();
});
```